# Can I set an explicit task timeout for RabbitMQ consumer?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I understand that RabbitMQ with ack, by default, will re-queue the message if it detects that the consumer/worker has died.

What about the situation where the consumer/worker is still alive but its process has stalled out for too long and didn't ack?

I would like to set an explicit time that says that if a message has been dispatched to a consumer but that consumer has held the message without ack for too long that the message gets re-queued.

I recognize that this might result in messages getting processed in duplicate but sometimes the consequence of that is not as bad as delayed message delivery.
It can also happen with errant exception handling if something get swallowed, the task terminates, and the message is never ack'd and never re-queued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeout for RabbitMQ consumer could be explicitly set on the consumer side. I think this is clear but just to mention - there must not be any automatic ACKs in this case. The solution would be that the consumer is multithreaded with one thread doing message processing and ACKing the message only after it has been processed, and the other thread being a timeout thread that would:

1. terminate the connection to broker once the timeout has expired, and
   as a consequence the message would be requeued
2. ACK the received message and re-publish it (explicitly)
3. NACK the received message, but [based on the documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html) (`instructing the broker to either discard them or requeue them`), it seems that some config should be set instructing the broker what should it do with NACKed messages

Now all this implies that at least some part of the process isn't stuck. If the whole process is stuck, perhaps the broker heartbeat towards the consumer is stopped and that is how the broker knows that the consumer died (honestly I didn't test this situation, so I'm  assuming), but if this is not the case (or simply to be extra safe) you could add some kind of a watchdog process that would be pinging the consumer(s) and killing them if there's no reply, which again would lead to the messages not being ACKed and being requeued.